# Cannot install OS on HP Proliant DL380 Gen9

Tags: redhat, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I'm trying to install RHEL6.1 on a new HP Proliant DL380 Gen9. When I got to the Storage options, I chose the "Basic Storage" option, but got an error saying "No Usable Disks found".

I can't access HP's Intelligent Provisioning page either because it seems to be "Attempting to connect to HP RESTful API" for a long time. If I press the F5 button, it increments the "Read Attempt" counter, and then seems to be stuck at "Attempting to scan hardware inventory and settings" for a long time.

Is the RHEL I'm trying to install too old? Is upgrading to a newer version, e.g. RHEL 7.2 my only option?

Comment: Have you created raid array in the bios?

Comment: There are multiple storage options for the DL380 Gen9, so in addition to answering @bgtvfr's question about creating a raid array, it's also important to understand which storage controller your DL380 has. That'll dictate which driver is needed.

Comment: You may also think to upgrade the firmware to the last update SPP...Witch the updated SPP 2018 you can access to the Intelligent Provisioning.

Answer (score 1):

According to HPE Servers Support & Certification Matrices:

http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/exceptions/rhel_exceptions.aspx

The min. supported version is RHEL 6.5 and I can confirm that we use RHEL 6.5 for installations on Gen9 HW successfuly.

---

Usually, there is some new HW, for which older versions of RHEL don't have drivers. For example our customized RHEL 7.2 isn't able to install on Gen10, because it detects local RAID storage provided by the SATA controller as removable. 7.4 detects it fine.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using this old of an operating system on new hardware.

The other answer is correct in that there's a minimum supported revision level. This is because over the life of the OS, newer hardware is released, and the base OS drivers are updated to accommodate. An OS installer released before your hardware existed runs the risk of driver incompatibility; usually NIC and array controller/storage.